# How to ensure a query happens before another query within the same function?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a function which has multiple queries set up in it. The function is long and involves alot, but works perfectly, save for one issue. There is a query which depends on some information with the query before and it occasionally crashes the app when the query before it is not totally done and caused the second one to unwrap a nil value. Here is the general setup:

```
func QueryandAppend(completion: (() -> Void)?){
    let userLinkQuery = PFUser.query()//query1
    userLinkQuery?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
        if let users = objects{
            for object in users{
                if let user = object as? PFUser{
                    userLinkArray[user.objectId!] = user.username
                }
            }
        }
        })

        let appendingQuery = PFQuery(classname: "Stuff")//query2
            appendingQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
            for object in objects{
               creatorArray.append(userLinkArray[object["User"] as! String]!)
            }
            ...
            completion!()

    }
```

The completion handler is used to make sure the entire function (and all of the queries) have been completed before running something in the `viewDidLoad()`. How do I ensure, though, that *within* the function query1 is done before query2 can run?

Comment: How exactly are the queries are executed, and which database are you targeting? Are the queries running in parallel a feature of the database, or are you using GCD?

Comment: @kennytm I am using a parse-server hosted by heroku as the DB. Them running in parallel isn't a particular feature. It was just a general set up that I had. I figured that since query1 was written before query2 it would always run first... kind of new at coding

Comment: I assume you are using the [Parse SDK](https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/ios/guide/)?

Comment: @kennytm yes that is what I am using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototypical way to do this with network and other asynchronous operations is to chain the operations, perhaps even break the individual network operations up each into a specific routine.  The individual operations have completion callbacks, so just invoke your second routine from the completion of the first.

```
func QueryandAppend(completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
    PFUser.query().findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
        guard error == nil, let users = objects else {
            completion?(false)
            return
        }

        for object in users {
            if let user = object as? PFUser,
                let objectId = user.objectId {
                userLinkArray[objectId] = user.username
            }
        }

        PFQuery(classname: "Stuff").findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
            if error != nil {
                // Handle error case
                completion?(false)
                return
            }

            for object in objects {
                creatorArray.append(userLinkArray[object["User"] as! String]!)
            }

            completion?(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, for a more modern stylistic approach, you could take a look at a good Promise framework, such as [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/)

Comment: can you explained what you meant by `if successful`? The actual query1 pulls an object and uses a parameter of this object to append an array. Can you explain your answer with more specifics to the code I have? I do not really understand the callbacks in the general sense (despite looking them up) I have edited the question with the specific code of the first query.

Comment: on both queries**